After Upgrade to 24.04, gdm is not showing up anymore
I upgraded my Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 on my Dell XPS notebook and it seemed to have run through successfully apart from some package named "summerpalace" which seems to be some Dell specific hardware information tool that depends on python3-distutils which itself are no longer available.
After doing a reboot gdm is not showing up anymore, I get a black screen with only a blinking cursor in the top left corner of the screen.
Using Ctrl+Alt+F3 to switch to a console I checked my Xorg.0.log but I don't see errors, except some warnings about some font paths that don't seem to exist, then there is the warning
(WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
which is probably fine I guess (since it's a laptop anyway)
and finally there is this warning which I don't understand to be honest:
xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)
(II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card1
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
There is no Xorg.conf file in /etc/X11/.
I tried uncommenting the line WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf which doesn't seem to make any difference.
I also tried removing and reinstalling gdm3 ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal with no luck as well as changing from gdm3 to lightdm.
In journalctl -b I found these lines:
gdm3[3261]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
systemd[1]: session-c7.scope: Deactivated successfully.
gdm3[3261]: Gdm: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: maximum number of X display failures reached: check X server log for errors
gdm3[3261]: Gdm: Child process -4116 was already dead.
gdm3[3261]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Any help is greatly appreciated!
